# Regarding $A_n$ Representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

I'm studying the irreducible representations of $A_n$, and there are some things that I don't find quite clear yet.

The article I'm following stems from Clifford Group Theory, and describes the relationship between irreducible representations of a group $G$, and those of a normal subgroup of order 2 $N$, such as $A_n$ in $S_n$. In particular, the article defines the *g-conjugate* (with $g \in G)$ of a $N$-irreducible representation $\sigma$ as $^h\sigma (n)=\sigma(h^{-1} nh)$ and the *inertia* of $\sigma$, $I_{G}(\sigma)$, as the elements of $G$ that satisfy $^{g}\sigma \cong \sigma$ as representations. The inertia group contains $N$ and is included in $G$, but with $N$ having order 2 as a subgroup of $G$, either $(i)$: $I_{G}(\sigma)=N$ or $(ii)$: $I_{G}(\sigma)=G$. We'll call $h$ a member of the only lateral class not equal to $N$, and $\epsilon$ the $G$-representation defined as: $\epsilon \space (g) = 1$ if $g \in N, \epsilon \space (g) = 0$ if not.

Now, a theorem that the article doesn't prove states that if $(i)$ stands, then if $\theta$ is the induced representation of $\sigma$ in G, then $\theta$ itself is irreducible in $G$ and restricting it to $N$ again gives us two $N-$irreducible representations, one is $\sigma$ and the other is its $h-$conjugate.

On the contrary, if $(ii)$ stands, and if $\theta$ is an irreducible $G-$representation that contains $\sigma$ when restricted to $N$, then the induced representation of $\sigma$ in $G$ is the sum of two irreducible representations, $\theta$ and $\theta \space \otimes \space \epsilon$ that again give us $\sigma$ when either of them is restricted to $N$.

Now, what I don't find clear at all is the application of these results in the context of $S_n$ and $A_n$. We know that the Specht modules $S^{\lambda}$, with $\lambda$ a partition of n, are a complete collection of irreducible $S_n$-representations. The article states that a complete set of irreducible representations of $A_n$ can be constructed in the following manner: if we denote $\lambda'$ as the transposed of $\lambda$, then for each non-symmetric partition, we choose either $\lambda$ or its transposed $\lambda'$, and the restriction of the relative Specht modules onto $A_n$ is still irreducible. For each symmetric partition, the restriction of the relative Specht module splits into two $A_n$-irreducible modules.

I really, really don't get how this is implied from the theorem before in any way. I think it stems from the fact that maybe if $\lambda$ is not symmetric, it falls into the $(ii)$ category, and the opposite if $\lambda$ is? And how do you prove that? Also, would that mean that, for any given non-symmetric $\lambda$ the two Specht modules $S^{\lambda}$ and $S^{\lambda^{'}}$ can be obtaining by the tensor product with $\epsilon$? Why is that? Also, do Specht modules associated with symmetric partitions fall in case $(i)$?

I'm sorry for the convoluted post, I hope I explained myself in a sufficient way, feel free to ask questions if the matter is still not clear enough.

Edit: $\epsilon$ is -1 in the complementary of N in G, not $0$

Comment: You need to know that the sign partition is labelled by $(1^n)$, and tensoring by the sign representation has the effect of mapping $S^\lambda$ to $S^\mu$, where $\mu$ is the conjugate partition to $\lambda$.

Comment: First of all thank you SO much, I never realized that epsilon in the context of $S_n$ and $A_n$ would be the sign representation... And now I get why those tensor products give us the Specht modules related to conjugate partitions. Still, why do we fall in one case or the other when we consider symmetric partitions or not? Why do we fall in the $(i)$ case and the $(ii)$ case with respectively symmetric and non-symmetric partitions?